# Install PEAR Mail/Mime Dependency issues in pure EPEL installation

Tags: yum, dependencies, pear, centos6.2, epel

Newbie in the sysadm area. Using Centos 6.2.

I am trying to install PEAR's Mime.php. I have successfully installed PEAR's Mail before. It's not going to well now for Mime.php.

This is what I do:

```
yum install php-pear-Mail-Mime
```

Gives dependency issues:

```
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-pear-Mail-Mime.noarch 0:1.8.2-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-mbstring for package: php-pear-Mail-Mime-1.8.2-1.el6.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-mbstring.i686 0:5.3.3-3.el6_2.6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common = 5.3.3-3.el6_2.6 for package: php-mbstring-5.3.3-3.el6_2.6.i686
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-mbstring-5.3.3-3.el6_2.6.i686 (updates)
           Requires: php-common = 5.3.3-3.el6_2.6
           Installed: php-common-5.3.10-2.el6.remi.i686 (@remi)
               php-common = 5.3.10-2.el6.remi
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-3.el6_1.3.i686 (base)
               php-common = 5.3.3-3.el6_1.3
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-3.el6_2.5.i686 (updates)
               php-common = 5.3.3-3.el6_2.5
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-3.el6_2.6.i686 (updates)
               php-common = 5.3.3-3.el6_2.6
```

php-mbstring requires the remi package for php-common it seems. I did try to update it:

```
yum --enablerepo=remi update php-common
```

But got:

```
No Packages marked for Update
```

And by mistake I did an install first and this is what I got:

```
Package php-common-5.3.10-2.el6.remi.i686 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

**UPDATE**: Checking my epel points to 6.5, I'm using Centos 6.2. Can this be a problem? (Aftermatch: This was not a problem)

```
rpm -qa | grep epel
epel-release-6-5.noarch
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appearently one should use the REMI repository for installing php-pear-Mail-Mime...

```
yum --enablerepo=remi install php-pear-Mail-Mime
```

Comment: One should do so when one also got PHP from that same repository. Remember to mark this question as resolved by clicking the check mark.